# invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c

In my code below, this line:

```
b[6] = Hello
```

Is throwing this error:

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
```

**Question**

Why am I receiving this error? Actually, all I want is to declare "b[6]" separately. Not like char b[6] = "Hello" like If I take a int variable say "int x" then i can easily declare it's value separately say "x = 2" but here, for string variable why I am unable to do that.

```
int a;
char b[6];

scanf("%d", &a);
if( a == 1)
    b[6] = "Hello";
else
    printf("Wrong");
```

Comment: What is `b[6]` after you have declared `b`? Is it an array or is the value of a single element in the array?

Comment: You only get one chance to **initialize** an array, that is when it is declared. Thereafter, you have to fill it yourself, either with a loop, `strcpy` (if you are handling a string), or `memcpy` if not.

Comment: Your description of what you are trying to do as described by you here " "int x" then i can easily declare it's value separately say "x = 2" " shows that you do not understand what the words you are using mean. When you are **setting** the value of `x` to `2` with `x = 2` you are **not** declaring it. You declare variables and then you use them. You have declared `b` to be an array of characters with a length of 6 when you write this `char b[6]`. To set the value of `b` then use `b = "Hello". You have a fundamental misunderstanding if the concepts you are working with and the words to use.

Comment: the posted code contains undefined behavior!   the array `b[]` is declared as containing room for 6 items.  In C, array indexes are in the range 0...(number of items in array -1)   I.E. 0...5  so `b[6]` is past the upper bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

In C, Strings are treated as `char` arrays, and the name of an array is treated as a pointer to the beginning of the array.

```
char b[6];
```

Based on this declaration, `b` is a pointer to the beginning of an array of 6 `char`s.

```
b[6] = "Hello";
```

This line attempts to set the 6th element of `b` to "Hello", but there's two problems with doing that:

1. `b[6]` does not actually exist. `b` is 6 elements long, beginning with index 0, so the highest index you can use is 5.
2. `b` is an array, so `b[6]` refers to a specific `char` whereas you attempt to set it to a String, i.e. a pointer to `char`, hence your error message.

If you're trying to make `b` hold the value of "Hello", there are a number of ways to do that. Theoretically, your method of `b = "Hello";` would work, but would probably be considered bad practice by most. The most basic is to set the values of the `char`s in the array to the letters in "Hello" one-by-one, followed by a `NULL` byte. Using the `<string.h>` standard library, you could (and probably should) do it using `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(b, "Hello");
```

Comment: strings are not the same as char arrays. Strings may be contained within char arrays. In `char b[6];`, `b` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: @M.M I never said strings were the same as `char` arrays, I said they were treated as `char` arrays. `b` is functionally an array, but the symbol `b` is a pointer to the character at the beginning of the array.

Comment: No, the symbol `b` is still an array. It *can be* implicity converted to such a pointer. You can test this out with `sizeof b`.

Comment: @M.M Well put - I forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

b`enter code here`[6] = "Hello";

Here you are assigning a char const * to a single char (and in addition that char is out of range).

If you want be to hold "H" do:

```
strcpy(b, "H");
```

Comment: Actually, all I want is to declare "b[6]" separately. Not like char b[6] = "Hello"

like If I take a int variable say "int x" then i can easily declare it's value separately say "x = 2"

but here, for string variable why I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

regarding: `

```
b[6] = "Hello";`
```

when an array is referenced; the result is the address of the first byte of the array.

So the statement is trying to assign the address of "Hello" to the char `b[]`.

Are you trying to fill the array `b[]`?  if so, then the proper method is:

```
strcpy( b, "Hello" );
```